# Pass parameter from ASP.Net MVC 3 to ASP.Net Webform

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, report

I created a report using SSRS and showed it in ASP.Net webfrom (not MVC aspx) with reportviewer. Then I integrated it with ASP.Net MVC 3 to show the report.

In my mvc 3 page, I have a button name "Config" which will open a jquery dialog. The dialog have some textbox, dropdownlist ....

How can I get value in the dialog and pass it to asp.net webfrom then the report will changed.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved Pass parameter from ASP.Net MVC 3 to ASP.Net Webform